# How to generate recurring payment fails test event for stripe subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

I developed a webhook for handling recurring payment failures of subscription. I want to test it for the expired card case. I tried to test it by creating invoice and trying to pay it using the expired test card which is available on https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments. But it is giving *The payment method must be attached to the customer*. But the above documentation says that you can not attach the card to customer object. Hence I tried to trigger invoice.payment.failed event using fixture. The fixture definition supports expected_error_type where I can specify card_error but there is no way to specify error code(expired_card).
How can I generate such event?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Decline after attaching" [test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments).

> Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail.

Comment: This test card generates card_error with card_declined error code. I want to generate expired_card error code. And if I try to attach "Expired Card Decline", stripe throws the error that the expired card can not be attached.

Comment: You are correct. There is no test card for that situation.